# Correct state immutability with rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, immutability

I have a subject with an object (state) with a lot of nested objects.

```
public testSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
    a : {
      prop: {...},
      prop1: {...}
    },
    b: {
      prop: {...},
      prop1: {...}
    },
   ...
  });
```

By my basic understanding of immutability with rxjs my first code of updating some of nested properties was like so (lets say I want to update `b`):

```
const copy = cloneDeep(this.testSubject.getValue());
copy.b = {...}
this.testSubject.next(copy);
```

Nested objects are updated very very (like up to each 1-5 sec) often in my application and I caught a problem that cloneDeep (any deep clone implementation) cause my app lugging (as my state is really big).

Somehow I need to reduce deep clone usage. I think about not replacing nested objects which were not changed but I am not sure if it's correct in terms of immutability. Smth like that:

```
const currentObject = this.testSubject.getValue();
const newB = {...}; // maybe deepCopy of currentObject.b + changes
this.testSubject.next({
  ...currentObject,
  b: newB,
});
```

Please let me know if it's okay in terms of immutability not to make a deep copy of all nested properties but only of changed nested objects and its children while updating a state (as it's showed in last code snippet)

Comment: AFAIK, your last code snippet will work fine as long as there are no functions in your state object.

Comment: This seems like a nice candidate for something like NGRX..

Answer (score 0):

Immutability guarantee that the instance your have is not modified by someone else while you are using it.

If you guarentee that you are controlling the modification of your object while you're processing it (or reading it) your second solution can be ok.

Answer (score 0):

As showed in examples here https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers it's okay to don't make a full copy of nested objects/arrays which was not changed.

But also what is important - we decided to normalize our state to get rid of deep nested objects.